# I want to add a element with prepend jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a new a element when I click the button but it doesnt work

```
<div id="add-container">
    <input type="text"> <button>add</button>
    <div id="megobrebi">
        <a>Levani</a>
        <a>Markozi</a>
        <a>Zuka</a>
        <a>Sandro</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-container').on('click', 'button', function(){
        var value = $('#add-container input').val;
        var html = '<a>' + value + '</a>'
        $('$megobrebi').prepend(html);
    })
})
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work" with specifics.

Comment: console gives me error

Comment: *What* error does it give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in the handler for the click event on the button.

First, you need to call the jQuery [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method in order to get the value of the input.

Second, the selector for the DOM element where you want to prepend is not right.

Therefore, the code should be:

```
$('#add-container').on('click', 'button', function(){
    var value = $('#add-container input').val();
    var html = '<a>' + value + '</a>'
    $('#megobrebi').prepend(html);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be

```
$('#megobrebi').prepend(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-container button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // You may use this line if you wish to disable the default functionality button.
        var value = $('#add-container input').val();
        var html = '<a>' + value + '</a>';
        $('#megobrebi').prepend(html);
    });
});
```